# Simple approach to synchronizing data across an Akka cluster?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, gossip

I've got some run-time data I'd like to exist on a designated actor on every node in my Akka cluster, which could be updated via internal event or API call to a single node. I could store this data in a shared database to make it permanent, but I'd rather just store it in memory for speed, since it doesn't need to be persisted. Akka Cluster Singleton, Distributed Pub Sub, and possibly other built-in modules use gossip protocols to keep distributed state in sync.

Is there a ready-built way to adopt data synchronization of my own actors across my cluster?

I've thought about just publishing changes to Distributed Pub Sub, but it seems like this wouldn't be resilient to dropped messages. If I stored it in a cluster singleton, it wouldn't be survivable if that node went down. I don't need persistence if the entire cluster goes down, but I do want resilience if individual nodes do.

Comment: Have you looked at akka distributed data? It is experimental, but sounds like a good fit for your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Akka Distributed Data](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/distributed-data.html), which should really be called "Akka Replicated Data", as it will replicate the data across all nodes. 
It provides a simple key-value store, and any changes made on one node will be replicated to all others. As *all* data is kept on *all* nodes, it's best used for small data sets. Also, the values in your key-value pairs need to be CRDTs (conflict free replicated data types). The module comes with some pre-defined CRDTs that cover a lot of use cases.

Comment: Yep. I've been using Distributed Data for months now. I probably should have answered my own question. It works great, although the API definitely leads to some intimidating looking code :)